# How to forward webhook data from JIRA using Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, jira, webhooks

I want to make a simple middle-man script which receives data from a JIRA webhook and then parses it and sends it over (to Discord, but that's not important).

From the looks of it, Cloud Functions was a perfect match, so I made a short script which just forwards the request json to a message on Discord to see what data it sends.

```py
import requests
import json
def forward(request):
    
    data = request.json
    #tried:
    #data = request.get_json()
    #data = request.data
    #data = request.values

    url = 'discord webhook receiver url'

    myobj = {'content': str(data)}
    requests.post(url, data = myobj)
    return '', 200
```

Set up the webhook on the JIRA side and it kinda works, but not really. First of all it doesn't trigger on some events, like adding a comment or editing a task, only for important(?) events, like adding a new task.
And secondly, it doesn't even send the right looking data for it. This is all i'm getting

```json
{'timestamp': 1609851709546, 'webhookEvent': 'issuelink_created', 'issueLink': {'id': 10016, 'sourceIssueId': 10007, 'destinationIssueId': 10022, 'issueLinkType': {'id': 10004, 'name': 'jira_subtask_link', 'outwardName': 'jira_subtask_outward', 'inwardName': 'jira_subtask_inward', 'style': 'jira_subtask', 'isSubTaskLinkType': True, 'isSystemLinkType': True}, 'sequence': 12, 'systemLink': True}}
```

And I know those 2 things are wrong because while testing it I've also set up another webhook for Pipedream, where it reacts to all changes, and the data contains names of issues, avatars, links. Everything that's needed for what I'm trying to do. And there aren't any differences between those 2 webhook settings, I have them both with all events selected.

So I've been at it for 2 days now with no breakthrough. Maybe I'm misunderstanding how webhooks work, or maybe cloud functions isn't the service to use for this. So while the question is how to do it in cloud functions, I'm also open to alternatives. (not the ones which do the formatting for you, as that's why I started making this in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Jira sends 2 requests on webhook trigger and the one containing all the useful info was just over the limit to be put into a Discord message so it never sent it.
That's what I get for using it for logging.

If anyone is also on the same dumbass path, then what I did to find that out is to save all the request data into a hastebin and send the link to it, like so.

```py
#pack it all into a hastebin
    everything = str(request.headers) + "\n" + str(request.data) + "\n" + str(request.args) + "\n" + str(request.form) +  "\n" + str(request.method) + "\n" + str(request.remote_addr)
    req = requests.post('https://hastebin.com/documents', data=everything)

#send the link id to discord
    myobj = {'content': req.text}
    x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)
```

All that's left is to parse and format the json.